# Notation in probability theory: conditional on multiple events or joint of event with an conditional one

Tags: probability, notation

It might be a quite dumb question and if so, I apologize in advance (I am kind of a newbie in probability theory ). But once in a while it bothers me and I can't find the answer to it.

Ok, now the question is as follows: if I have a probability written like this:

$P(A|B,C)$

does this mean that

*) A is dependent on B and C or that

*) it is an joint distribution of A|B and C

and if the first is true, how would I write the second one?

Comment: Oh nice, thank you very much!

Comment: @RoryDaulton The link is broken.